# flex countdown algorithm

Tags: apache-flex

The algorithm must take in an Int-value of the number of seconds remaining (ex. 2005), then convert and return a "0-padded-String" of the hours, minutes, and seconds remaining (ex. 02:35:15).

I have another event handler that will invoke the above algorithm change in seconds (count down).

Comment: Can you show us some code which you've attempted thus far?

Comment: This site is a place to get questions answered, not a place to get people to do your work for you.  Show is your code you've attempted so far and then tell us what you've been having problems with and we may be able to offer assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation for your conversion method:

```
public static function Seconds2HHMMSS(Time:Number):String 
    {
        var hours:int =int(int(Time/60)/60);
        var hoursZeroPadding:String = "";
        if (hours<10)
            hoursZeroPadding="0";

        var minutes:int =int(Time/60)%60;
        var minutesZeroPadding:String = "";
        if (minutes<10)
            minutesZeroPadding="0";

        var seconds:int =Time%60;
        var secondsZeroPadding:String = "";
        if (seconds<10)
            secondsZeroPadding="0";

        var result:String =    hoursZeroPadding + hours.toString()
                            + minutesZeroPadding + minutes.toString()
                             + secondsZeroPadding + seconds.toString();
        return result;
    }
```

The opposite conversion is quite simpler:

```
    public static function HHMMSS2Seconds(Time:String):int 
    {   
        var result:int =   int(Time.substr(0,2))*3600 
                         + int(Time.substr(2,2))*60 
                         + int(Time.substr(4,2));   
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `div` and `mod` and your knowledge of how many seconds in an hour / min / second to come up with each of the groupings. You can then do a padding of zeros with an if statement (or the ?: operator)

**Edit:** or just use Dunaril's code, I didn't want to just give you the code without you having tried something first, that goes against the spirit of SO for me :P

Comment: I agree that this is not the best way for @vas to improve his programming skills, but it so appeared that I had the snippet at hand when I saw the question, so I thought it would be faster for everyone :)

Comment: That's quite alright, I didn't mean it as a shot at you or anything, I like that SO is able to help provide answers (especially on pretty basic questions) but I just left this here so the OP hopefully realizes that they shouldn't continue this in the future :D